# Can I put Firebase ValueEvent listener in Application class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use Firebase Value event listener in 5 activities. And all listeners are going to do same work, so can I put listener in Application class and remove listener when application is terminated?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private RefWatcher refWatcher;
    private ValueEventListener value_event_listener;

    public static RefWatcher getRefWatcher(Context context) {
        MyApplication application = (MyApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
        return application.refWatcher;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
        EmojiManager.install(new IosEmojiProvider());

        if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
            // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
            // You should not init your app in this process.
            return;
        }
        refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this);

        value_event_listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          //TODO
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //TODO

            }
        };
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(C.DELIVERY).addValueEventListener(value_event_listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(C.DELIVERY).removeEventListener(value_event_listener);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes but there is a cleaner way to approach it.

A more [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) approach would be to create a utility class that is called from each place you want to listen for this event. In this way you can extend the utility class should your requirements change in the future. The change can then be applied without potentially affecting all locations where this is used.

It also makes this more testable since you can mock out the utility class to verify different scenarios.